# iOS Simulator Stuck at Launch Screen after Adding Crashlytics and Force Crashing the App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, crashlytics

I have Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics enabled for my Swift App. But something strange happens, Whenever i crashed my app using simulator, the next time i open my app, it stucks at the launch screen. However, it works well on the real device.

Here's my custom **run script** at **build phase** :

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/path/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

I have also added these scripts on **input files** :

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}

$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to clean derived data & run again, if it does not work, try to use following:

```
"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

instead of:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/path/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work on my case. I have done what you recommended, but when i crash the app then re-open again, it still stuck on the launch screen. 
I've no idea why this thing only happens on the simulator. The dSYM file successfully uploaded, so i think i have no issue with Firewall (my firewall is turned off).